# BinaryFormatter in objective c

Tags: objective-c, binaryformatter

i have function in my .net app

```
Public Shared Function SerializeMessageByString(ByVal msg As Object) As Byte()

        Using m As New MemoryStream()

            Dim bin As New BinaryFormatter()
            bin.Serialize(m, msg)

            Return m.ToArray()
 End Using
```

this value is coming to my iPhone application how do i convert bytes of binary to string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSData *bytesData = data;//bytes 
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:bytesData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: NSData *bytesData = cm.msgBytes;
    NSString *cmdata = [[NSString alloc] bytesData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

is this correct syntax ? i am getting a error saying Expected ':'

Comment: Thanks , how can i get the encoding of 1252 ? not utf8

Comment: i changed it by NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding but still i am getting ÿÿÿÿ£ is front of received text , the data sent is in 1252

Answer (score 0):

let your bytes be represented by:

```
char * inData;
```

now convert to an NSString:

```
NSString * strRep = [NSString initWithBytes:inData length: theLenInBytes encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

assuming UTF8 encoding, if your data isn't UTF-8 or a subset the init will return nil.